# SQL to copy values from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql

In Table B, for each `id` that doesn't have `key=right`, I need to create it and copy `value_A` to `value_B`.

Example:

**Before state**

Table A

```
id      value_A
1500    R20
1501    R21
1502    R22
```

Table B

```
id      key     value_B
1500    left    L20
1500    right   R20
1501    left    L21
1502    left    L22
1502    right   R22
```

**After state**

Table A

```
id      value_A
1500    R20
1501    R21
1502    R22
```

Table B

```
id      key     value_B
1500    left    L20
1500    right   R20
1501    left    L21
1051    right   R21
1502    left    L22
1502    right   R22
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `insert`.  One method uses `not exists`:

```
insert into b (id, key, value_b)
    select a.id, 'right', a.value_a
    from a
    where not exists (select 1
                      from b
                      where b.id = a.id and b.key = 'right'
                     );
```

Comment: How do you ```select a.id, 'right', a.value_a``` since ```'right'``` doesn't exist in Table A?

Comment: @BB3CPO . . . It is a constant value.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. I posted a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64406022/insert-row-and-copy-value-from-same-table)