# Insert row and copy value from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a follow-up question to my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64404143/sql-to-copy-values-from-one-table-to-another).

The requirement now is:

In Table B, for each id that has `key='left'` but doesn't have `key='right'`, I need to create a new row with `key='right'` and copy `value_B` of the row with `key='left'` to `value_B` of the new row with `key='right'`.

**Before**

Table B

```
id      key     value_B
1500    left    X20
1500    right   X20
1501    left    X21
1502    left    X22
1502    right   X22
1503    middle  X23
```

**After**

Table B

```
id      key     value_B
1500    left    X20
1500    right   X20
1501    left    X21
1501    right   X21
1502    left    X22
1502    right   X22
1503    middle  X23
```

Answer (score 1):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
insert into TableB(id, `key`, value_B)
select b.id, 'right', b.value_B 
from TableB b
where b.key = 'left'
and not exists (
  select 1 from TableB
  where id = b.id and `key` = 'right' 
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=53d5bcf768ed1c1f8df6839adf63b810).
Results:

```
>   id | key    | value_B
> ---: | :----- | :------
> 1500 | left   | X20    
> 1500 | right  | X20    
> 1501 | left   | X21    
> 1501 | right  | X21    
> 1502 | left   | X22    
> 1502 | right  | X22    
> 1503 | middle | X23
```